# My collisions will not work, so how can I fix it?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, collision

I am making a game where the player hits the ball against a wall and it bounces off, but as I was setting up the player and the wall I tried to make it so you can collide with the wall, but I phased right through.

Btw, I have tried get_rect(topleft = (X, Y)), but that didn’t work either script:

```
import pygame
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 700, 600
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
GREY = [117,117,117]
Player = pygame.image.load("Player.png")
Wall = pygame.image.load("Wall.png")
PX = 0
PY = 0

def draw_window():
    global GREY
    global Player
    global PX
    global PY
    WIN.fill(GREY)
    WIN.blit(Player, (PX,PY))
    WIN.blit(Wall, (510,0))
    Black = [0,0,0]
    Wall_rect = Wall.get_rect()
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, Black, (510, 0, Wall.get_width(), Wall.get_height()), True)
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, Black, (PX, PY, Player.get_width(), Player.get_height()), True)
    pygame.display.update()

def main():
    global PX
    global PY
    global Wall
    global Player
    Wall_rects = Wall.get_rect(topleft = (510,0))
    Wall_rect = pygame.Rect(510, 0, Wall.get_width(), Wall.get_height())
    Player_rect = pygame.Rect(PX, PY, Player.get_width(), Player.get_height())
    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        speed = 1.5

        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            PX -= speed
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            PX += speed
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            PY += speed
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            PY -= speed
        if pygame.Rect.colliderect(Wall_rect, Player_rect):
            print("COllision")
        draw_window()
main()
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so from looking at your code it seems like the collision should be working fine. The player is phasing through because you haven't put anything in your code to make it stop at the wall by stopping it moving in a certain direction. Is 'COllision' being printed? If so, then it is most likely the reason I suggested, if not then it may probably be an issue with the collision detection.

Comment: No it is not printing COllision or anything at all.